# firefox - set default search engine

Tags: firefox, search-engines, system-preferences

Can the default search engine be set in prefs.js for firefox?  Or, is it still not possible as per [How to set duckduckgo as default search engine using user.js?](https://superuser.com/questions/1372679/how-to-set-duckduckgo-as-default-search-engine-using-user-js)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This idea was recently submitted on 07-13-2022 to the
Mozilla Connect community in the post
[Allow user.js to set default search engine](https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/ideas/allow-user-js-to-set-default-search-engine/idi-p/9898).

This idea is open for votes and there had been three such votes (only).

Voting for it yourself is about the best that you can do at the moment.